# How to make recursive promise

Tags: javascript, ajax, asynchronous, promise, crud

I want to add retry logic to my javascript HTTP service, which internally uses Axios and returns promises. Goal is to retry fetch/post until it resolves or retry limit is exceeded. I came up with this draft (not working as it is)

```
fetchSomething(numRetry) {

        if (!numRetry)
            numRetry = 0

        return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
            axios.get('/services/rest/vopa/sanomaloki/virheet')
                .then(response => resolve(response))
                .catch(response => {
                    if (numRetry > FETCH_RETRY_LIMIT)
                        reject(response)
                    else
                        return fetchSomething(numRetry + 1)
                })
        });
    }
```

As far as I know, calling fetchSomething in catch creates new resolve and reject functions, but I would like it to resolve or reject the original promise

Comment: return fetchSomething(numRetry ++)

Comment: Think better call your function insider of 'reject' callback, on one abstraction level higher

Answer (score 0):

How about this simpler version (untested!):

```
function fetchSomething(numRetry = 0) {
    return axios.get('/services/rest/vopa/sanomaloki/virheet')
        .catch(response => {
            if (numRetry > FETCH_RETRY_LIMIT)
                return Promise.reject(response); // pass it on
            else
                return fetchSomething(numRetry + 1); // might work
        });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to create a new `Promise`. Actually using Promise constructor indicates you are doing something wrong. [Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/2sduyxpe/).

```
function fetchSmth(num) {
    num = num || 0

    return num > FETCH_RETRY_LIMIT
        ? Promise.reject(new Error('Fetch retry limit reached'))
        : axios
            .get('/services/rest/vopa/sanomaloki/virheet')
            .catch(fetchSmth.bind(null, num + 1))
}
```